# Breakline in JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I store every text in my application in a settings.ts file, but I need to add some breaklines and \n appears not to work. Is there any other way I should could these breaklines? I'm working with Next.js, React and TypeScript.

```
export const text = 'this is my text that \nshould have a breakline'

<div>{text}</div>
```

Comment: `<div>{text.split('\n').map(it => <p>{it}</p>)}</div>`

Comment: You need some CSS magic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\n`, you can use another option `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre-wrap`

```js
const text = 'this is my text that \nshould have a breakline'

const App = () => <div className="break">{text}</div>

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.break {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```